# STL iterator of superclass calling subclass method

Tags: c++, stl, polymorphism

I have not used C++ in a while, so I'm not sure what the right way is to do what I'm trying to do. I have the following classes:

```
class A {
public:
   virtual string printStuff() { return "A"; };
};

class B : public A {
public:
   string printStuff() { return "B"; };
};

class C : public A {
public:
   string printStuff() { return "C"; };
};
```

I have an STL vector:

```
vector<A> vec;
```

It contains a lot of class A and B objects. When I do:

```
for (vector<A>::iterator iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter) {
   iter->printStuff();
}
```

All it prints is "A". I would like it to use class B and C's methods.

Thank you.

Comment: `vector<A>` can only possibly hold objects of type `A`. Look up ["object slicing"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

Comment: Your vector holds a bunch of object sliced to A, polymorphism is lost (store unique_ptr's)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `std::vector<A>` can *only* contain objects of type `A`. If you insert an object of a derived class type, it will be sliced. If you want polymorphic behaviour, use `std::vector<A*>` (or, better, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>`).

Comment: Thanks. What is the advantage of using unique_ptr<A> over <A*> ?

Comment: @SquallLeohart there is no possibility of leaking memory or other resources with a smart pointer

Comment: It seems like my C++ does not support unique_ptr. Any workaround?

Comment: @SquallLeohart If you can't upgrade your compiler, I guess you'll just have to use `A*`.

Comment: @SquallLeohart: What compiler are you using, and did you `#include <memory>`?

Comment: c++ , and yes I did include memory